# Get data with function - sqlite3 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I wrote a code, my goal is to easily retrieve information from the sqlite3 database without always having to do "db.get ..." so I make a function but it doesn't work , can you help me ?

Here is the code:

```
exports.getGuildLanguage = function(guild) {
var lang = null;

db.get("SELECT guildLanguage FROM a" + guild.id, (err, data) =>{
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    lang = data;
    (data.guildLanguage);
})

return lang;
};
```

in "getters.js" file
And in another class

```
const getters = require("../getters.js") // récupération du fichier
console.log(getters.getGuildLanguage(message.guild)) // envoie du message
```

Please help me !
Thanks for your reponse in advance

PS : Sorry, my english is bad because I am french

Comment: What kind of error returns you the console?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I think you should make it an async function that returns a promise. Or you add a second argument to the function, that is a callback and you call it inside with the result. Returning a Promise however will be preferred solution today in modern javascrip. Because you can directly use the function with async/await.